# ImageResizer preserve metadata

Tags: imageresizer

Does any one know if there is a way to tell ImageResizer to preserve image metadata (IPTC, XMP etc) ?.

This was a feature that was supposed to make it into 3.4 but I can't seem to find any documentation for it, and out of the box the metadata is still removed.

If this feature was not added, does anyone know any similar image resizers that offer this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [`ImageResizer.Plugins.CopyMetadata`](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/copymetadata). It was released with [V3.4.3](http://imageresizing.net/releases/3-4-2).

When installed, you can use the `&copymetadata=true` command to copy metadata onto the resulting image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am having trouble getting this to preserve IPTC or XMP on jpegs. Are these formats supported?

Comment: IPTC & EXIF metadata should be preserved. XMP metadata is not supported.